# How can I turn off the power to an outlet if a water alarm is triggered?

Tags: electrical, water, leak, dishwasher

I'm installing a dishwasher on a second floor, and after having 3x dishwashers leak during their run cycle during my life, I'm understandably hesitant.

I will definitely be installing a water alarm. However, what I'd really like to do is install a water alarm that can shut off power to the dishwasher in case of a leak.

Does such a device exists without me rigging up my own setup using a relay and water alarm combination?

Comment: An emergency drain pan would be a good idea too

Comment: @Paul I added one for the laundry (and a floor drain, also) but a preformed pan might be hard to add and still be able to un- and re- install a dishwasher.  If I absolutely had to protect the area 100%, I add a floor drain and use Schluter or Noble waterproofing membrane to make a pan-in-place.

Answer (score 4):

I just recently paired a leak detector with a power relay for an upstairs laundry.

The leak detector has an output contact that is sensed by the power relay.

[Floodstop detector, leak sensor and single valve for dishwasher](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000QZ6ALW)

[Furman power relay](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0002CZQIC)

I bought an extra sensor (they connect easily in parallel), so that I had one in the pan and one just outside at the base of the wall.

No extra wiring is necessary, except for converting your DW to a plug and outlet, all other wiring is supplied

You don't have to connect the valve if you don't want to, but its extra insurance if a hose leaks.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The above wet switch flood detector is for 24V.  You'll need one for 110v, which is this one:
[WaterWatcher Leak Detector 110v](http://amzn.to/2iOqBBP)

As you know, with a dishwasher, you need to more than cut off the flow into the unit. One of the most likely leaks will occur in the drain hose, due to thirsty rodents. Such a leak can be hidden until your floor starts bubbling up (ask me how I know!)

There are also flood prevention connectors that are quite reasonably priced, which will shut off the water into the unit if the flow exceeds what it should be (indicating something is broken). They are made of braided stainless steel, which you can also get without the added flood protection shut off, but it's cheap insurance.   They make them for toilets, sinks, and washing machines as well.

[Watts FloodSafe Dishwasher Connector Kit](http://amzn.to/2iOh3Xp)

Personally, I go with both!

Answer (score -3):

I know there are valves for washing machine that do this. Like this one: http://www.pexsupply.com/Watts-0004646-A2C-WB-IntelliFlow-Automatic-Washing-Machine-Water-Shutoff-Valve-w-Leak-Sensor?gclid=COb8w-qC4rUCFQSg4Aod0mQAaw

It could probably be used for dishwasher as well.

Comment: I need something to shut off power, not water.

Answer (score -4):

Try wet switch flood detector

[http://www.amazon.com/DiversiTech-WS-1-Switch-Flood-Detector/dp/B004JPDO8W](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004JPDO8W)

Comment: That is for an HVAC condensate pan running on 24v, rather than a 120v dishwasher.